# Creating a textarea preview before submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please guys, I want to create a page which works just like the [STACKOVERFLOW](http://stackoverflow.com)
that displays the texts instantly just exactly the way it's been writen when typing in a textarea, I am not to good at javascript but I did figure out this code:

```
$("#comment").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
       $('#preview').css('display','none');
    }else{
       $('#preview').css('display','block');
    }
    $("#preview").html($(this).val());
    // $("#preview").text($(this).val()); // If you want html code to be escaped
    $("#preview").html($("#preview").html().replace(/`x3`/g,'<div id="code_put" class="code_put">'));
    $("#preview").html($("#preview").html().replace(/`z3`/g,'</div>'));
    var code = document.getElementById('code_put').innerHTML;
    $("#code_put").text(code);
    $("#code_put").html($("#code_put").html().replace(/!--/g,''));
    $("#code_put").html($("#code_put").html().replace(/--/g,''));
});
```

But It doesn't break down to the next line in the preview div when I press the enter key as it breaks down in the textarea. I guess this is not a better approach to achieving my aim. Please if anyone has a better approach to this I would appreciate it very much.

And if possible I also want the codings in the textarea to display in a gray div also just as in stackoverflow because I added something like such in my code but I guess that's not a better method of doing that.

here is the html code:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="preview" class="preview">
</div>
```

it's not much and I guess its not relevant.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you drop this into a JSFiddle?

Comment: Also could we see the HTML that corresponds to this? We don't need the whole page, just the stuff relevant to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem you mention in your post, namely that newlines aren't kept, can be fixed with a simple line of CSS:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

However, there are other things wrong with your code. Most importantly, you are repeatedly assigning to the element's `innerHTML` (albeit through jQuery's `.html()` function) and reading from it too. You should almost never read from `innerHTML`...

Instead, start with `preview = $(this).val();`, then perform your various replacements or parsing on `preview`, and then finally, at the very end, `$("#preview").html(preview);`

Comment: Thanks Niet... But do you think my method of approach is a good one?

Comment: No I do not. You should parse the text, not apply blind regex replacements on it, but that's just like my opinion :p Writing a parser is a LOT more work, but the results are so much better.

Comment: Thanks I will go for it

Comment: Please I don't really know how to parse a text. I have searched but couldn't find a suitable solution. Can you please give me clue on how it's done or a link where I can find a better explanation

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, I'd suggest either making your #preview `<div>` into a #preview `<pre>`, or adding this css:

```
#preview {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

That ought to make the newlines in the textarea show up correctly in the preview `<div>`.

Here's an example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/00nmk83y/